# Swift 3 - Singleton

Tags: singleton, swift3

```
class MyManager {

private static var __once: () = {
    Static.instance = MyManager()
}()

class var sharedInstance: MyManager {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: Int = 0
        static var instance: MyManager? = nil
    }
    _ = MyManager.__once
    return Static.instance!
}

fileprivate init() {
    print("MyManager init");

}
....... etc
```

calling it

```
 aManager = MyManager.sharedInstance
```

results in

```
 MyManager init fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_ = MyManager.__once` isn't calling your `__once` function, it's assigning it to nothing. You forgot the `()`:

```
 MyManager.__once()
```

That's the whole purpose of requiring `_ =`, to make you realize you're dealing with the function itself, not a function call.

Regardless, this is an unnecessarily convoluted and messy implmentation of a singleton. All you need is:

```
class MyManager {
    static let instance = MyManager()
}
```

It's lazy, thread-safe, and sane.

Comment: The problem is if I don't delete the brackets I get by the compiler  'cannot call value of non-function type ()'

Comment: Also, your `__once` function isn't a function, its type is `()`, a.k.a. `Void`. You need it to be `() -> ()`. In any case, don't do any of this lol, it's horrid

Comment: Thank you I won't be doing it  :)

Comment: Have I satisfied your question?

Comment: Yes you did , was trying to carry Swift 2 ways onto Swift 3

Comment: This isn't even "Swift 2 ways" lol This is Objective C ported without any regard for Swift's features/techniques

Answer (score 0):

For me this is the best way, make init private.

```
// MARK: - Singleton

final class Singleton {

    // Can't init is singleton
    private init() { }

    // MARK: Shared Instance

    static let shared = Singleton()

    // MARK: Local Variable

    var emptyStringArray : [String] = []

}
```